# Why am i getting the following error while installing Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, live-usb

I have a Dell xps with windows 10 installed on it. I am trying to live boot linux mint. I used rufus to create a usb and when i boot in to it and try to install linux mint, i get the following error: "intel raipd technology is enabeled on your device disable and try again" can somebody please help me out?
I am trying to install it on to my flash drive not on the one that i have windows 10 installed, so why am i getting this error?

Comment: Have a read of https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347 I'm not in this situation myself so I don't feel qualified to adapt this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Go into your bios and disable `fast startup` and `secure boot`.

Google for `How to disable Fast Startup in Windows 10`.

Same for `Secure boot`.

Comment: Can you also say something about "why am i getting this error?" which is the actual question.